# How to start a VNC server in C?

Tags: c, vnc

I need to open a lightweight X server in C language. I figure vnc may be lightweight enough and universal in all Linux flavor and windows. Is there a C API to start vnc server? What libraries does it need?

Comment: A VNC server and an X Windows server do very different things, so I'm baffled at your question.

Comment: After starting vnc server, it always starts window manager and a X server established. That's why I want to start vnc server.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the binary (executable) that you want to start, you can probably just use `system()` to start it. Assuming the binary is in <kbd>/usr/bin/vncserver</kbd>:

```
system("/usr/bin/vncserver");
```

Note though, as pointed out in a comment, that your question is fairly confused. A VNC server is *not* an X server. It's perfectly possible to run a VNC server without running X "inside" it. So starting a VNC server will most likely not help with your problem. I suggest you post a new question with a more clear description of what you're trying to achieve, this sounds a lot like you're "jumping" to a solution.

Comment: OK. I was expecting something in C API other than directing calling the command. But yes the question I wrote wasn't very clear.